# Compiler Mode in Magento

Tags: magento, compiler-construction

What is compiler mode in Magento?

I want to know this concept, Let me know if any one knows?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google -> "magento compiler mode" [first hit](http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path):

> It turns out that having PHP search for a large number of include
>   files over a large number of different directories can create a
>   performance bottleneck under certain types of load. To combat this,
>   the Magento core team created the Magento Compiler extension, and
>   started shipping Magento with this functionality around version 1.4
>   CE.
>
> What the compiler does is makes a copy of every class in a Magento
>   system and places them in a single folder. The class’s full name is
>   used for the filename to ensure uniqueness
>
> include/src/Mage_Core_Model_Abstract.php
>
> include/src/Foo_Module_FooController.php
>
> etc...
>
> This is done once. Then, when Magento is configured to use the
>   compiler classes, its autoload will look in the compiler folder
>   instead of running its normal autoload routine. This spares PHP the
>   overhead of transversing the file system for all the different include
>   paths.

Comment: You really want to do testing to make sure this actually speeds things up for you. For example, my webserver has a RAID array that is pretty fast. Having the compiler enabled actually made things go slower for me. I would get to know how the Apache Benchmarking tool works so you can do your own tests.

Comment: Also, I've run into strange bugs when compiler mode is enabled. It's also a hassle to recompile every time you push an update, in addition to clearing cache. I read somewhere that the Magento team recommends not using it, since it's not as necessary with recent releases of Magento.